# VIsual studio : tool for exporting excel data to resource file

Tags: excel, visual-studio, resources, multilingual, resx

I want to export excel data of multiple languages to resource files in Visual studio and i do not want to copy paste each single row (key and value) to resource file as i have data for about 7 web pages with each page containing 20 rows.

I have worked on exporting .resx to .xlsx earlier using a very good tool : http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html but it does not work otherwise (.resx to .xlsx)

One major challenge i am facing is: the number of rows in excel are less than the number of key-values in .resx i.e i do not have the whole content translated in excel

I have tried microsoft's in-built tool (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbwz4bhx(v=vs.90).aspx) but it imports excel as excel/csv itself and not as .resx

2. Also giving a try to http://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/
   which is throwing error : could not find a matching file in Solution..

Any suggestions for tried and tested tool will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

http://resxresourcemanager.codeplex.com/ could help but it always throws errors saying sheet and solution's resx file names does not match, even if you create a rex file on root and provide same name to excel sheet.

So i opted for manual copy-paste.. was not much time consuming :)